# How to compile %z specifier in my code with dev-c++ editor

Tags: c, gcc, c99, dev-c++, c11

I have to compile a c program files with %zu specifier but the printf function always show zu without showing the true value. I have use dev-C++5.11 and my TDM_GCC is version 4.9.2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main(void) {
   const size_t x = 150;
   int a[x];
   for (size_t i = 0;i < x; ++i)
      a[i] = i;
   printf("SIZE_MAX = %lu\n", SIZE_MAX);
   size_t size = sizeof(a);
   printf("size = %zu\n", size);
}
```

And the result is

> SIZE_MAX = 4294967295
>
> size = zu

May I know how to make compiler show the true value in the size.
Thanks You.

Comment: `printf("size = %u\n", size);` --> `printf("size = %zu\n", size);`

Comment: The code you posted prints 600 for size in dev c++

Comment: Maybe %zu specifier may not be use in my compiller, although I use -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 but why it can print sizeof but cannot print %zu?

Comment: @lawrence In devc++, the best way to print a size_t value is to use %lu and cast the value to an unsigned long.

Comment: Okay, Thanks You for your comment.

Comment: @lawrence dev-C++ is not a compiler. You're probably using the MingW compiler which in turn uses the MSVCRT C library... and this is a known issue

Comment: Thanks You for your comment.